# Residue distributions are not uniform

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

With $n_1$ and $n_2$ two positive integers, the formula

$$L = \sum_{k=0}^{498}\, \left(n_1+n_2\, k \right) {(10^{6})}^{k}$$

can construct very large numbers $L$.

Once we have $L$ we can let $n$ vary from $1$ to $1,000,000$ and construct residues

$$n \mapsto [L \pmod n] \pmod {53}$$

The residues will all belong to $\{0,1,2,\dots,52\}$. Since we are taking $1,000,000$ residues, you might guess that each residue will occur around $\frac{10^6}{53} \approx 18,868$ times, but this is not the case.

I wrote a Python program (see next section) and found the following distributions:

```
Please input big number seed 1: 1
Please input big number seed 2: 2
seeds = 1 2
[(16, 37359), (25, 19262), (4, 19164), (13, 19153), (26, 18985), (1, 18972), (41, 18885), (15, 18855), (12, 18814), (7, 18766), (46, 18766), (29, 18755), (50, 18746), (20, 18735), (10, 18716), (39, 18701), (9, 18638), (33, 18638), (45, 18626), (48, 18575), (18, 18573), (43, 18569), (31, 18527), (22, 18511), (5, 18509), (2, 18459), (8, 18454), (38, 18449), (21, 18443), (0, 18440), (34, 18430), (49, 18422), (23, 18416), (47, 18413), (35, 18409), (17, 18405), (42, 18401), (27, 18400), (36, 18399), (28, 18321), (32, 18320), (14, 18302), (3, 18294), (24, 18278), (44, 18167), (30, 18162), (19, 18153), (40, 18152), (52, 18123), (37, 18083), (11, 18068), (51, 17996), (6, 17841)]

Please input big number seed 1: 123
Please input big number seed 2: 321
seeds = 123 321
[(48, 36932), (13, 19246), (2, 19144), (18, 19060), (29, 19047), (42, 18992), (49, 18840), (21, 18830), (47, 18801), (22, 18797), (39, 18768), (20, 18767), (3, 18734), (1, 18698), (52, 18693), (15, 18679), (25, 18675), (5, 18661), (0, 18655), (28, 18629), (7, 18628), (17, 18623), (32, 18613), (8, 18608), (46, 18604), (19, 18593), (33, 18562), (4, 18531), (51, 18497), (9, 18496), (14, 18477), (38, 18476), (36, 18443), (30, 18439), (44, 18408), (23, 18382), (24, 18372), (41, 18371), (43, 18327), (45, 18314), (34, 18269), (11, 18208), (26, 18207), (31, 18164), (35, 18148), (37, 18145), (10, 18133), (50, 18117), (27, 18112), (12, 18063), (40, 18035), (6, 18012), (16, 17975)]

Please input big number seed 1: 88
Please input big number seed 2: 78
seeds = 88 78
[(16, 37746), (7, 19142), (40, 19121), (23, 19050), (38, 18929), (51, 18921), (42, 18904), (1, 18845), (20, 18826), (15, 18761), (39, 18758), (41, 18748), (4, 18746), (6, 18697), (0, 18663), (31, 18652), (11, 18646), (48, 18617), (17, 18580), (22, 18569), (9, 18563), (12, 18559), (24, 18541), (26, 18516), (8, 18509), (45, 18491), (36, 18489), (28, 18474), (32, 18447), (25, 18446), (37, 18438), (50, 18433), (52, 18430), (46, 18394), (49, 18383), (18, 18356), (29, 18356), (14, 18337), (3, 18328), (43, 18318), (33, 18314), (10, 18286), (13, 18261), (19, 18260), (44, 18221), (2, 18219), (47, 18201), (5, 18178), (34, 18175), (21, 18144), (35, 18088), (30, 17964), (27, 17960)]
```

Notice how the first most common residues stand out:

$(16, 37359)$
$(48, 36932)$
$(16, 37746)$

in each of the three programs runs.

I started out using $\text{mod } 50$ and that pattern was really weird so I tried using the prime number $53$. It works better but still not looking uniform.

> Any explanation for this distribution pattern?

**My work and motivation**

I'm interested in cryptography and was thinking that if two parties shared a secret large number $L$ they could transmit $n$ to represent one of, say, $53$ characters.

So with seeds $= 1,\, 2$ and $(25, 19262)$ counter output, you have $19,262$ different choices for $n$ to transmit the $25^{th}$ character of your 'alphabet'. Of course you can find more $n$ by going past the (artificially} selected one million mark.

> Any answers/comments on the strengths and weaknesses of this idea would be appreciated.

---

**Python program (not optimized)**

```
M = 1000000

def bP(i):
    p = 1
    for j in range(0, i):
        p = (p * M)
    return p

def getTerm(i):
    return ((n1 + n2 * i) * bP(i)) 

import collections

while True:
    print()
    n1 = int(input('Please input big number seed 1: '))
    n2 = int(input('Please input big number seed 2: '))
    print('seeds =',n1,n2)
    L = 0
    for i in range(0, 499):
        L = (L + getTerm(i)) 
    cnt = collections.Counter()
    for n in range(1, 1000001):
        c = (L % n) % 53
        cnt[c] += 1
    print(cnt.most_common())
```

Comment: To get a uniform distribution I tried setting $L$ to a large prime, $L = 1000000016531$ and letting $n$ vary from $1,000,001$ to $2,000,000$ and same thing happens: $\quad [(11, 37392), (42, 18898), (48, 18897), (47, 18884), (0, 18800), (37, 18781), (40, 18750), (31, 18708), (13, 18695), (1, 18673), (36, 18648), (52, 18626), (24, 18625), (22, 18623), (46, 18608), (45, 18602), \dots, (16, 18229), (32, 18203), (30, 17986)]$

Comment: Generating random numbers is hard. So is cryptography. Hand built off the top of one's head ideas like this are not likely to be very secure. I suspect there is some elementary number theory at play here that explains the phenomena you observe. Try reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator

Comment: @EthanBolker I liked the fact it would be difficult to perform frequency analysis - we can keep changing $n$ for the same letter many times. By the time you run of  $n$'s or whenever circumstances dictate, you can change $L$, perhaps by perturbing it using a Diffie–Hellman key exchange.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks for the linear congruential generator link. I see (now) the fundamental role of randomness in designing state of the art cryptographic systems, but this was more of an amateur foray into ciphers. Found this quote for you. $\quad$ John von Neumann: Anyone who considers arithmetical methods of producing random digits is of course in a state of sin.:

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain the math behind the distribution, but the following shows that there is tracking 'lock-on' that occurs.

Here we simplify:

$L = 1000$

Alphabet divisor $p = 7$

Let $n$ range from $1$ to $500$.

Here the residue

$r = [L \text{ mod } n] \text{ mod } p = 6$

'sticks out' with the highest $n$ frequency count for $r = 6$. When $n = 126$ the residue pattern 'locks onto' $r = 6$ and tracks it up to $n = 142$.

Following is a detailed printout showing $r = 6$ and for comparison, $r = 0$
(the other residues display '*' in the $r\text{-column}$).

The summary report is

$\text{[(6, 91), (0, 77), (3, 73), (1, 67), (4, 67), (5, 65), (2, 60)]}$

So the 'one-off uniform' pattern is found again for these program parameters.

Here is the output of the Python demonstration program with column headings
$\text{L } \text{ n }\text{ L-mod(n) }\text{ r }\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad $ (the code is in the next section).

```
1000 1 0 0
1000 2 0 0
1000 3 1 *
1000 4 0 0
1000 5 0 0
1000 6 4 *
1000 7 6 6
1000 8 0 0
1000 9 1 *
1000 10 0 0
1000 11 10 *
1000 12 4 *
1000 13 12 *
1000 14 6 6
1000 15 10 *
1000 16 8 *
1000 17 14 0
1000 18 10 *
1000 19 12 *
1000 20 0 0
1000 21 13 6
1000 22 10 *
1000 23 11 *
1000 24 16 *
1000 25 0 0
1000 26 12 *
1000 27 1 *
1000 28 20 6
1000 29 14 0
1000 30 10 *
1000 31 8 *
1000 32 8 *
1000 33 10 *
1000 34 14 0
1000 35 20 6
1000 36 28 0
1000 37 1 *
1000 38 12 *
1000 39 25 *
1000 40 0 0
1000 41 16 *
1000 42 34 6
1000 43 11 *
1000 44 32 *
1000 45 10 *
1000 46 34 6
1000 47 13 6
1000 48 40 *
1000 49 20 6
1000 50 0 0
1000 51 31 *
1000 52 12 *
1000 53 46 *
1000 54 28 0
1000 55 10 *
1000 56 48 6
1000 57 31 *
1000 58 14 0
1000 59 56 0
1000 60 40 *
1000 61 24 *
1000 62 8 *
1000 63 55 6
1000 64 40 *
1000 65 25 *
1000 66 10 *
1000 67 62 6
1000 68 48 6
1000 69 34 6
1000 70 20 6
1000 71 6 6
1000 72 64 *
1000 73 51 *
1000 74 38 *
1000 75 25 *
1000 76 12 *
1000 77 76 6
1000 78 64 *
1000 79 52 *
1000 80 40 *
1000 81 28 0
1000 82 16 *
1000 83 4 *
1000 84 76 6
1000 85 65 *
1000 86 54 *
1000 87 43 *
1000 88 32 *
1000 89 21 0
1000 90 10 *
1000 91 90 6
1000 92 80 *
1000 93 70 0
1000 94 60 *
1000 95 50 *
1000 96 40 *
1000 97 30 *
1000 98 20 6
1000 99 10 *
1000 100 0 0
1000 101 91 0
1000 102 82 *
1000 103 73 *
1000 104 64 *
1000 105 55 6
1000 106 46 *
1000 107 37 *
1000 108 28 0
1000 109 19 *
1000 110 10 *
1000 111 1 *
1000 112 104 6
1000 113 96 *
1000 114 88 *
1000 115 80 *
1000 116 72 *
1000 117 64 *
1000 118 56 0
1000 119 48 6
1000 120 40 *
1000 121 32 *
1000 122 24 *
1000 123 16 *
1000 124 8 *
1000 125 0 0
1000 126 118 6
1000 127 111 6
1000 128 104 6
1000 129 97 6
1000 130 90 6
1000 131 83 6
1000 132 76 6
1000 133 69 6
1000 134 62 6
1000 135 55 6
1000 136 48 6
1000 137 41 6
1000 138 34 6
1000 139 27 6
1000 140 20 6
1000 141 13 6
1000 142 6 6
1000 143 142 *
1000 144 136 *
1000 145 130 *
1000 146 124 *
1000 147 118 6
1000 148 112 0
1000 149 106 *
1000 150 100 *
1000 151 94 *
1000 152 88 *
1000 153 82 *
1000 154 76 6
1000 155 70 0
1000 156 64 *
1000 157 58 *
1000 158 52 *
1000 159 46 *
1000 160 40 *
1000 161 34 6
1000 162 28 0
1000 163 22 *
1000 164 16 *
1000 165 10 *
1000 166 4 *
1000 167 165 *
1000 168 160 6
1000 169 155 *
1000 170 150 *
1000 171 145 *
1000 172 140 0
1000 173 135 *
1000 174 130 *
1000 175 125 6
1000 176 120 *
1000 177 115 *
1000 178 110 *
1000 179 105 0
1000 180 100 *
1000 181 95 *
1000 182 90 6
1000 183 85 *
1000 184 80 *
1000 185 75 *
1000 186 70 0
1000 187 65 *
1000 188 60 *
1000 189 55 6
1000 190 50 *
1000 191 45 *
1000 192 40 *
1000 193 35 0
1000 194 30 *
1000 195 25 *
1000 196 20 6
1000 197 15 *
1000 198 10 *
1000 199 5 *
1000 200 0 0
1000 201 196 0
1000 202 192 *
1000 203 188 6
1000 204 184 *
1000 205 180 *
1000 206 176 *
1000 207 172 *
1000 208 168 0
1000 209 164 *
1000 210 160 6
1000 211 156 *
1000 212 152 *
1000 213 148 *
1000 214 144 *
1000 215 140 0
1000 216 136 *
1000 217 132 6
1000 218 128 *
1000 219 124 *
1000 220 120 *
1000 221 116 *
1000 222 112 0
1000 223 108 *
1000 224 104 6
1000 225 100 *
1000 226 96 *
1000 227 92 *
1000 228 88 *
1000 229 84 0
1000 230 80 *
1000 231 76 6
1000 232 72 *
1000 233 68 *
1000 234 64 *
1000 235 60 *
1000 236 56 0
1000 237 52 *
1000 238 48 6
1000 239 44 *
1000 240 40 *
1000 241 36 *
1000 242 32 *
1000 243 28 0
1000 244 24 *
1000 245 20 6
1000 246 16 *
1000 247 12 *
1000 248 8 *
1000 249 4 *
1000 250 0 0
1000 251 247 *
1000 252 244 6
1000 253 241 *
1000 254 238 0
1000 255 235 *
1000 256 232 *
1000 257 229 *
1000 258 226 *
1000 259 223 6
1000 260 220 *
1000 261 217 0
1000 262 214 *
1000 263 211 *
1000 264 208 *
1000 265 205 *
1000 266 202 6
1000 267 199 *
1000 268 196 0
1000 269 193 *
1000 270 190 *
1000 271 187 *
1000 272 184 *
1000 273 181 6
1000 274 178 *
1000 275 175 0
1000 276 172 *
1000 277 169 *
1000 278 166 *
1000 279 163 *
1000 280 160 6
1000 281 157 *
1000 282 154 0
1000 283 151 *
1000 284 148 *
1000 285 145 *
1000 286 142 *
1000 287 139 6
1000 288 136 *
1000 289 133 0
1000 290 130 *
1000 291 127 *
1000 292 124 *
1000 293 121 *
1000 294 118 6
1000 295 115 *
1000 296 112 0
1000 297 109 *
1000 298 106 *
1000 299 103 *
1000 300 100 *
1000 301 97 6
1000 302 94 *
1000 303 91 0
1000 304 88 *
1000 305 85 *
1000 306 82 *
1000 307 79 *
1000 308 76 6
1000 309 73 *
1000 310 70 0
1000 311 67 *
1000 312 64 *
1000 313 61 *
1000 314 58 *
1000 315 55 6
1000 316 52 *
1000 317 49 0
1000 318 46 *
1000 319 43 *
1000 320 40 *
1000 321 37 *
1000 322 34 6
1000 323 31 *
1000 324 28 0
1000 325 25 *
1000 326 22 *
1000 327 19 *
1000 328 16 *
1000 329 13 6
1000 330 10 *
1000 331 7 0
1000 332 4 *
1000 333 1 *
1000 334 332 *
1000 335 330 *
1000 336 328 6
1000 337 326 *
1000 338 324 *
1000 339 322 0
1000 340 320 *
1000 341 318 *
1000 342 316 *
1000 343 314 6
1000 344 312 *
1000 345 310 *
1000 346 308 0
1000 347 306 *
1000 348 304 *
1000 349 302 *
1000 350 300 6
1000 351 298 *
1000 352 296 *
1000 353 294 0
1000 354 292 *
1000 355 290 *
1000 356 288 *
1000 357 286 6
1000 358 284 *
1000 359 282 *
1000 360 280 0
1000 361 278 *
1000 362 276 *
1000 363 274 *
1000 364 272 6
1000 365 270 *
1000 366 268 *
1000 367 266 0
1000 368 264 *
1000 369 262 *
1000 370 260 *
1000 371 258 6
1000 372 256 *
1000 373 254 *
1000 374 252 0
1000 375 250 *
1000 376 248 *
1000 377 246 *
1000 378 244 6
1000 379 242 *
1000 380 240 *
1000 381 238 0
1000 382 236 *
1000 383 234 *
1000 384 232 *
1000 385 230 6
1000 386 228 *
1000 387 226 *
1000 388 224 0
1000 389 222 *
1000 390 220 *
1000 391 218 *
1000 392 216 6
1000 393 214 *
1000 394 212 *
1000 395 210 0
1000 396 208 *
1000 397 206 *
1000 398 204 *
1000 399 202 6
1000 400 200 *
1000 401 198 *
1000 402 196 0
1000 403 194 *
1000 404 192 *
1000 405 190 *
1000 406 188 6
1000 407 186 *
1000 408 184 *
1000 409 182 0
1000 410 180 *
1000 411 178 *
1000 412 176 *
1000 413 174 6
1000 414 172 *
1000 415 170 *
1000 416 168 0
1000 417 166 *
1000 418 164 *
1000 419 162 *
1000 420 160 6
1000 421 158 *
1000 422 156 *
1000 423 154 0
1000 424 152 *
1000 425 150 *
1000 426 148 *
1000 427 146 6
1000 428 144 *
1000 429 142 *
1000 430 140 0
1000 431 138 *
1000 432 136 *
1000 433 134 *
1000 434 132 6
1000 435 130 *
1000 436 128 *
1000 437 126 0
1000 438 124 *
1000 439 122 *
1000 440 120 *
1000 441 118 6
1000 442 116 *
1000 443 114 *
1000 444 112 0
1000 445 110 *
1000 446 108 *
1000 447 106 *
1000 448 104 6
1000 449 102 *
1000 450 100 *
1000 451 98 0
1000 452 96 *
1000 453 94 *
1000 454 92 *
1000 455 90 6
1000 456 88 *
1000 457 86 *
1000 458 84 0
1000 459 82 *
1000 460 80 *
1000 461 78 *
1000 462 76 6
1000 463 74 *
1000 464 72 *
1000 465 70 0
1000 466 68 *
1000 467 66 *
1000 468 64 *
1000 469 62 6
1000 470 60 *
1000 471 58 *
1000 472 56 0
1000 473 54 *
1000 474 52 *
1000 475 50 *
1000 476 48 6
1000 477 46 *
1000 478 44 *
1000 479 42 0
1000 480 40 *
1000 481 38 *
1000 482 36 *
1000 483 34 6
1000 484 32 *
1000 485 30 *
1000 486 28 0
1000 487 26 *
1000 488 24 *
1000 489 22 *
1000 490 20 6
1000 491 18 *
1000 492 16 *
1000 493 14 0
1000 494 12 *
1000 495 10 *
1000 496 8 *
1000 497 6 6
1000 498 4 *
1000 499 2 *
1000 500 0 0

[(6, 91), (0, 77), (3, 73), (1, 67), (4, 67), (5, 65), (2, 60)]
```

---

**Python Program**

```
import collections

    L = 1000    
    cnt = collections.Counter()
    for n in range(1, 501):
        c = (L % n) % 7
        if c == 6 or c == 0:
            print(L, n, L % n, c)
        else:
            print(L, n, L % n, '*')  
        cnt[c] += 1
    print()
    print(cnt.most_common())
```