# Uniform residue limits over $\{1,2,\dots,p-1\}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, conjectures

Let $p$ be a prime and $m \ge 1$.

Define the ($p$ residue of a residue) function

$\tag 1 \gamma_{(p,m)}: [1, pm] \to \{0,\dots,p-1\}$
$\tag 2 \quad \quad  \quad \quad  \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \; n \mapsto [pm \pmod n] \pmod {p}$

Define

## $\quad u_{(p,m)} = pm - \text{#}\bigl(\gamma_{(p,m)}^{-1}(0)\bigr)$

For $1 \le r \le p -1$ define

## $\quad v_{(p,m,r)} = \frac{\text{#}\bigl(\gamma_{(p,m)}^{-1}(r)\bigr)}{u_{(p,m)}}$

> Please prove that
>
> ## $\tag 3 \lim_{m \to \infty} v_{(p,m,r)} = \frac{1}{p-1}$

While the proof is missing (or $\text{(3)}$ is refuted), allow me to make it a conjecture.

**My Work**

This came about from my investigations over [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3273390/432081).